# Бинарный поиск интервала

Tags: алгоритм, поиск

Есть массив `1 2 3 ... N`. Известно, что этот массив можно разбить на три интервала `[1 2 .. .L-2 L-1]`, `[L L+1 ... R-1 R]`, `[R+1 R+2 ... N-1 N]`, `(L<=R)` так что каждый элемент из своего интервала дает определенный результат в функции `f`. `f(1)=f(2)=...f(L-1)`, `f(L)=f(L+1)=...f(R)`. `f(R+1)=f(R+2)=...f(N)`.

Как за `logN` (какой-нибудь модифицированный бинарный поиск) найти эти `L` и `R`?

Comment: Нужно найти сам интервал или его длинну?

Comment: Я кажется понял. Тут нужно два бинарных поиска. Для начала интервала и для конца.

Comment: Объясню поподробнее. Есть массив 1 2 3 ... N. Известно, что этот массив можно разбить на три интервала [1 2 .. .L-2 L-1],    [L L+1 ... R-1 R],      [R+1 R+2 ... N-1 N],  (L<=R)            так что каждый элемент из своего интервала дает определенный результат в функции f.          f(1)=f(2)=...f(L-1)             f(L)=f(L+1)=...f(R)                f(R+1)=f(R+2)=...f(N).     Как за logN (какой-нибудь модифицированный бинарный поиск) найти эти L и R?

Comment: @talex Да, что-то в этом роде. Мне нужен пример кода правда.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Извиняюсь что на Джаве.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = {1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3};

        Interval interval = find(0, arr.length - 1, i -> arr[i]);

        System.out.println(interval);

    }

    static Interval find(int start, int finish, Function<Integer, Object> f) {
        int intStart = findStart(start, finish, f) + 1;
        int intEnd = findStart(intStart, finish, f);
        return new Interval(intStart, intEnd);
    }

    private static int findStart(int start, int finish, Function<Integer, Object> f) {
        int a = start;
        int b = finish;
        Object aO = f.apply(start);
        Object bO = f.apply(finish);
        while (a + 1 < b) {
            int m = (a + b) / 2;
            Object mO = f.apply(m);
            if (aO.equals(mO)) {
                a = m;
            } else {
                assert bO.equals(mO);
                b = m;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    @Data
    private static class Interval {
        private final int intStart;
        private final int intEnd;
    }
}
```

Comment: Надо еще потестить на граничные условия.